# Невозможно разобрать что происходит на экране во время установки

Tags: linux, archlinux, bios

Пытаюсь, установить archlinux, делал загрузочную флеку с помощью Rufus и belenaEtcher. Далее, в bios выбираю флешку загрузки и появляется, вот это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом, выбираю первый пункт и появляется вот это:
[image: l]

И всё, команды вводить могу, но всё отображается в соответствующем качестве.
Как с этим бороться?
Если что материнская плата от asus, но не думаю, что это на что-то влияет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В efi загрузчике не знаю(попробую завтра), а в грабе нажимаешь `E` и к параметрам запуска ядра добавь nomodeset, noapic, nolapic. После установки и установки драйверов на видео убирешь эти параметры в /etc/default/grub.

Comment: да, помогло, спасибо, правда, до момента установки драйверов ещё не добрался

Comment: картинка будет тормозить с `nomodeset`

Comment: хорошо, учту - спасибо

Answer (score -3):

Попробуй установить образ просто через Rufus (смотри видео), просто выбираешь ISO, FAT32 и USB, и всё. ~_~